# Is $A\cup B=A\cup \{B\cap A^c\}$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I am reading the book "Statistical Inference" by Casella and Berger. I was wondering if an identity in Theorem 1.2.9 b is correct. They proves the following:

If $P$ is a probability function and $A$ and $B$ are any sets in sigma-algebra $\mathcal B$, then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Their proof starts as follows:

To establish (b), we use the identity
$$A\cup B=A\cup \{B\cap A^c\}.$$
Should this be
$$A\cup B=A\cup (B\cap A^c)?$$

Comment: yes, the second line is the right one ... probably just a typo

Comment: What is the difference between expressions $ \{B\cap A^c\}$ and $ (B\cap A^c)$?

Comment: The same mistake seems to be in part (a) of the same problem so I was just wondering if I'm totally lost with sets but thanks! @Vlad: $\{B\cap A^c\}$ is a set containing one element, $B\cap A^c$ but $(B\cap A^c)$ can contain different number of elements.

Comment: @Vlad: '{' and '}' are often (especially in the current context) reserved to denote a set. This is clearly not intended here.

Comment: Some people use $\{$ and $\}$ as a variant form of parentheses; it's ill-advised, for exactly the reason you note — that it's ambiguous with the notation for sets presented by listing their elements — but they do it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, we write:

$$A\cup B=A\cup (B\cap A^c)$$
and then open the brackets, using set theory, 
$$A\cup B=(A\cup B) \cap (A\cup A^c)$$
=> $$A\cup B=(A\cup B) \cap (U)$$
=>$A\cup B$. ( U is the universal set).

Answer (score 3):

$ A\cup (B\cap A^c)  = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup A^c)\\
                     = (A \cup B) \cap U  \\
                     = A \cup B $